# Batch copy only modified files

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have two folders (say Source and Working). Now within these, there are 100s of other files/folders.

Now, the folder Source gets updated periodically (i.e. some files/folders may change or get added). I am trying to keep both the folders in sync.

So I need a batch command such that only the files/folders which are new/modified in "Source" get updated into the  "Working" folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not need a bat file. Just use the [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) with some parameters. Try:

```
xcopy <path to source> <path to destination> /D /E /C /Q /H /R /Y /K 



source  Specifies the file(s) to copy.
destination Specifies the location or name of new files.
/A  Copies only files with the archive attribute set, doesn't change the attribute.
/M  Copies only files with the archive attribute set, turns off the archive attribute.
/D:m-d-y    Copies files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.
/EXCLUDE:file1 [+file2][+file3]...  Specifies a list of files containing strings. When any of the strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be copied, that file will be excluded from being copied. For example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the .obj extension respectively.
/P  Prompts you before creating each destination file.
/S  Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
/E  Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
/V  Verifies each new file.
/W  Prompts you to press a key before copying.
/C  Continues copying even if errors occur.
/I  If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
/Q  Does not display file names while copying.
/F  Displays full source and destination file names while copying.
/L  Displays files that would be copied.
/H  Copies hidden and system files also.
/R  Overwrites read-only files.
/T  Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes empty directories and subdirectories.
/U  Copies only files that already exist in destination.
/K  Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.
/N  Copies using the generated short names.
/O  Copies file ownership and ACL information.
/X  Copies file audit settings (implies /O).
/Y  Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
/-Y Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
/Z  Copies networked files in restartable mode.
/B  Copies the Symbolic Link itself versus the target of the link.
/J  Copies using unbuffered I/O. Recommended for very large files.
```

Comment: Hmm..Thx a lot...Could you pls explain the specific parameter which would ensure that only the modified files/folders get copied..

Comment: Please look at the link provided in xcopy: http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

Comment: I am trying xcopy C:\Documents and Settings\myName\Desktop\trial\source C:\Documents and Settings\myName\Desktop\trial\destination /D /E /C /Q /H /R /Y /K

Comment: Quote the paths: I am trying xcopy "C:\Documents and Settings\myName\Desktop\trial\source" "C:\Documents and Settings\myName\Desktop\trial\destination" /D /E /C /Q /H /R /Y /K

Comment: Hey...that's perfect..one last question...Though not completely related...Actually not sure if you know about SVN...But actually my source is a versioned SVN folder and I want to copy all files into my destination (but without the versioning)...So any way to do that...I'll accept this even if you do not answer this...

Comment: AFAIK subversion stores the version information in a .svn folder. Please look at the /exclude parameter for xcopy to exclude all the files in that folder.

Comment: Is there a way to use this to delete files that weren't in the source folder? e.g. - if I want to copy files test1.txt & test2.txt into a folder named "backup" which contains test1.txt, test2.txt, & old_irrelevant_file.txt, how can I get it to delete the old_irrelevant_file.txt?

Answer (score 14):

/D:m-d-y    Copies files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.

So only the /D and /Y parameter are needed to answer the original question:

```
xcopy <source> <destination> /D /Y
```